# Get "resource not found" on Azure speaker identification API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create a new speaker profile using the speaker identifier API of Microsoft Azure.

This is how it looks like on postman -
[params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llL7N.png)
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7LUW.png)
Endpoint URL - https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken/speaker-recognition/verification/text-independent/profiles?api-version=2021-09-05

The body -
{
locale: "en-gb"
}

The response I get
{
"error": {
"code": "404",
"message": "Resource not found"
}
}

Any idea why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by creating a speech service in azure portal and copied the `key1` as shown in the below image:

[image]

We need to use the below endpoint :

```
 https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speaker-recognition/verification/text-independent/profiles?api-version=2021-09-05
```

I have passed the the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` and value as key1 which is taken from azure portal as shown in the above image, in the **Authorization** tab in postman like shown below:

[image]

Added the **header** `content-type`with value as `application/json` and in the **body** tab added `locale` with value as `"en-gb"` as shown below:

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Also, I have also tested in the [browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/verification/text-independent/create-profile?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0) and initially got the 404 error after passing this url-`https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken`

[image]

[image]

**Note**: we have to pass the endpoint with only **protocol** and **hostname** and remove the additional path from the above endpoint.

`https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`

***Output after removing the additional path from the endpoint and got the output successfully***:
[image]
[image]